# Avoid heavy calculations in a view

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work with large table (5 billions rows). So, I have a view. It's a simple view but with a lot of column. Looks like:

```
Select
       Column1,
       Column2,
       Column3,
       ...
       Column40
From 
     Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
     ...
     Table7 INNER JOIN Table8
```

One of the columns(Lets's say Column3) has a heavy string series operations. View looks like:

```
Select
       Column1,
       Column2,
                    COALESCE(...
                 , ( SUBSTRING
                       ( LTRIM(RTRIM(....)))
                       , PatIndex('%[^0]%', LTRIM(RTRIM(...))
                       , PatIndex('%[^1]%', LTRIM(RTRIM(...))
                       , PatIndex('%[^2]%', LTRIM(RTRIM(...))
                       , PatIndex('%[^3]%', LTRIM(RTRIM(...))))
                       , len(LTRIM(RTRIM(...))))
                       , len(LTRIM(RTRIM(...))
                       , len(LTRIM(RTRIM(...))
                       )
                 )) Column3,
       ...
       Column40
From 
     Table1 INNER JOIN Table2
     ...
     Table7 INNER JOIN Table8
```

So, when someone trying to select data from this view, it take a long time (like forever). This issues appears only when someone add Column3 in filter.

I want to avoid this situation. So, I wanna ask you about ideas...My thoughts on this are to create a trigger and calculate this value at the time of insertion. Maybe there's another options?

Comment: What makes you think that the `Column3` is the issue here?

Comment: @Larnu This issues appears only when someone add Column3 in filter

Comment: Think if all those calculations are really required and how can they be simplified. If not, at some point, the price must be payed and the calculation made. Another option would be for the view to only provide the raw data and the client doing the calculation itself.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a trigger, but I would use a persisted computed column that calculates the value automatically when a row is inserted: however, you will still have to "pay the price" somewhere, so now your inserts might be slower. And, it will need to immediately compute every row, so the initial operation could take a long time. [Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-ver19) some info from Microsoft.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But query time is more inportnant for us, then time of insert. Thank you

Comment: Then this would work for you. That field will get populated and persisted automatically and your query just includes that computed column without all the text manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

A complex column is slow when you use it in a filter because the database can't know if the column will match the filter or not for any given row until it computes the final value. This means it needs to compute this value for **ALL 5 billion rows in the table**. When you instead choose to filter on other columns it only needs to compute this value for rows in the final result set.

Really there are only three things you can do to help this:

1. Throw more hardware at it
2. Avoid filtering on the column, at least at the database level.
3. Pre-compute the column value in some way.

For #1, this can including revising parallelization settings to take better advantage of the existing CPU.

For #2, assuming this view ultimately feeds into other tools, those tools might be configured to look at other things first when initially pulling in data, and then still allow filtering on the complicated column after the data is loaded. For example, it's common to have reporting tools load data into a web page and display using, say, [datatables.js](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array), where you can search within the local dataset after loading the base data from the DB.

For #3, options include a converting to a [materialized view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-materialized-view-as-select-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) or, if all the source data for the column is from the same original table, updating that table to use a computed column. Just keep in mind both options add significant storage and performance costs to your database every time the data changes.

Typically, at some point with a large table like this the organization will decide it's okay seeing data that's slightly stale for a certain class of reports, and decide to start loading into a data warehouse on some recurring schedule (often nightly), where this column can handled as part of the repeating ETL process.

Comment: Thank you. I will consider materialized view. But Can you explain please, what's the difference between computed column and trigger approach? All the source data from the same function

Comment: A trigger is really a second statement that runs in addition to an INSERT or UPDATE. A computed column is _part of the table definition_. I almost always prefer a computed column. Triggers are easier to get wrong in subtle ways, and I tend to worry about them missing an update or locking the table more. However, sometimes you're working with a vendor database where changing table definitions is not an option.